# Error in gmin(date) : min is not meaningful for factors

Tags: r, plot

```
mydata <- read.csv("C:/Users/rs1a17/Desktop/mydata.csv")

plotTimingPatterns(mydata,n=30,T.cal="2004-01-01",headers = c("Past", "Future"), title = "")
```

> Error in gmin(date) : min is not meaningful for factors.

How to solve this question?

---

my data is like this:

```
   cust       date
2000015 1993-11-05 
2000015 1993-11-25 
2000015 1994-12-06 
2000015 1997-10-01
```

and I write

```
mydata$date<-as.character(mydata$date)
```

Then

```
plotTimingPatterns(mydata,n=30,T.cal="2004-01-01",headers = c("Past", "Future"), title = "")
```

Comment: Convert your date column to a `Date` class so it's not a factor. See `?Date`, or search Stack Overflow for "[r] convert date".

Comment: Thanks a lot, while I think my date is in right format, so I do not know how to convert it.

Comment: Right. So did you look at the help page `?Date` or search stack overflow for "[r] convert data"? Those are both good ways to learn how to convert it. Since you haven't shared any reproducible example data (I don't have `mydata.csv` on my desktop), the best I can do is point you to good resources. If you want code in an answer, you should (a) show what you've tried, and (b) share a reproducible example. [Here's a great walkthrough of how to make reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061) if you need help with that.

Comment: sorry, I am the new learner of R and my data is like this:  
cust                         date
2000015             1993-11-05
2000015             1993-11-25
2000015              1994-12-06
2000015              1997-10-01    and  I write "mydata$date<-as.character(mydata$date)" Then "plotTimingPatterns(mydata,n=30,T.cal="2004-01-01",headers = c("Past", "Future"), title = "")"

Comment: @RuixueSun ; you're almost there, but instead of coercing to `character` class you likely need to change it to `Date` class - see `?as.Date` ps if `plotTimingPatterns` is from a package can you add these details please

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I manage to do it.